# Unable to mount X,X GB Volume

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, usb

This issue occurs on `x64 ubuntu 14`. The volume is standard usb pendrive and an error look like this:

[image]

Regards

Comment: do you have another computer at hand where you can test the pendrive as it seems (at least) the filesystem on the drive is somehow in a bad shape.

Answer (score 0):

USB flash drives can fail.  Although originally written for data recovery on spinning, magnetic media, [SpinRite](https://www.grc.com/sr/testimonials.htm) may help you recover data from flash drives too.